# Changing rotation for each data driven page dynamically?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, data-driven-pages

I have a .mxd using data driven pages. In the .mxd there is a shape containing foto locations displayed with an arrow. At the top of the arrow there is a label containing the foto id visualized, the roation of the arrow is the direction of view of each photo. 
The problem now is, that the data driven pages have different rotations, so the labels are not positioned right in each page. I am using the adjusting placement by rotation setting.
How can I dynamically change the rotation for each data driven page for each lable?

Comment: Would you be able to include a picture and more details about what you are trying to do, please?

Comment: No I do not want to include a picture! I only want to visualize the photo number in the direction of the arrow! But I solved the problem in the way how seamster02 answered the question "Rotating hatch labels based on orientation changes in Data Driven Pages Strip maps?"